# CSRF token not properly handled when calling a function

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We're using SAP Cloud SDK 3.32.0 with SpringBoot.
We've generated a typed OData service based on the EDMX metadata file generated by the service and use the generated client in our code. All logs entries showing our issue are below (cleaned them up a bit to show the important parts only)

The situation is the following:

- We send a `myservice.createEntity(MyEntity).exectureRequest(myDestination)` with the generated client. Since this is a modifying/creating call, the client first requests a CSRF token. This works fine as shown in the logs below (first HEAD and POST calls)
- Next we call a function with `myservice.myFunction(p1, p2, p3).executeRequest(myDestination)`. This is a function exposed by the same OData service, so the service path is the same. Since this function is a `POST`, the client will again try to fetch a CSRF token. However, this results in a `HTTP 403 Forbidden` status code. We do not get the CSRF token (see second `HEAD` request in the logs below).
- The function call is still executed, but with an empty `X-CSRF-Token` http header (second POST request in logs).
- Although we seem to receive a response from the OData service, the client finallly times out (Read time out) and we are unable to process the result of the function call.

Debugging/clicking through the code of the CloudSDK, I discovered that the generated "FluentHelperFunction" class has it's own logic for retrieving the CSRF token (e.g. it uses "Fetch" in the HEAD requests), where as the FluentHelperCreate class uses the DefaultCsrfRetriever class (which uses lower case "fetch" for the HEAD call).

So my questions are:

- Why does the HEAD call for CSRF fail when done by a function call (i.e. `myservice.myFunction()`)
- Why does the FluentHelperFunction class have it's own logic for getting a CSRF token?
- What can I do to make this work properly. Or is this a bug in the SDK?

Logs:

```
=== HEAD before create entity - Returns CSRF token OK -
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"HEAD http://dev-gateway-cd:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV HTTP/1.1[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"x-csrf-token: fetch[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Accept: application/json[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Content-Type: application/json[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Proxy-Authorization: Bearer eyJh...." }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"SAP-Connectivity-Authentication: Bearer eyJh...." }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"X-Requested-With: X-Requested-With[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"sap-language: en[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Host: dev-gateway-cd:443[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11.0.8)[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.02+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.10+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.10+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"content-type: text/html[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.10+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"content-length: 0[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.10+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"x-csrf-token: 38IQnzDSn6aZeqmFczbqQA==[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.10+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"sap-processing-info: microhub=,crp=,st=,MedCacheHub=,codeployed=,softstate=-[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.10+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"sap-perf-fesrec: 28128.000000[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.10+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"set-cookie: sap-usercontext=sap-language=en&sap-client=550; path=/[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.10+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"set-cookie: MYSAPSSO2=AjQxMDMBABhBAEwAMgAyADIANwA2ACAAIAAgACAAIAACAAY1ADUAMAADABBEAEcAVwAgACAAIAAgACAABAAYMgAwADIAMAAxADEAMQA5ADAANwA1ADQABQAEAAAACAYAAlgACQACRQD%2fASswggEnBgkqhkiG9w0BBwKgggEYMIIBFAIBATELMAkGBSsOAwIaBQAwCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMYH0MIHxAgEBMEcwOjEVMBMGA1UEChMMU0FQIFNlY3VyaXR5MSEwHwYDVQQDExhTZWN1cmUgTG9naW4gVXNlciBTdWIgQ0ECCQQz%21dD%2f97ncUTAJBgUrDgMCGgUAoF0wGAYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQUxDxcNMjAxMTE5MDc1NDU3WjAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQU4PBXYuos4C1Bm%21YztJ4J8CdsGQ4wCQYHKoZIzjgEAwQuMCwCFCavVSRTFJsKNa3srFhnEbOByT8GAhRHSbed50wUDAOB4AYClz%2ftvf3pYg%3d%3d; path=/; domain=dev-gateway-cd; HttpOnly[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.10+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"set-cookie: SAP_SESSIONID_DGW_550=4BFhS5Wq30GRv2nbzjuNh4RHkVUqPBHrpSgCOIUjX_g%3d; path=/; HttpOnly[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.10+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"[\\r][\\n]\"" }

=== POST Create entity - Uses CSRF token from previous HEAD request -
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"POST http://dev-gateway-cd:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV/HeaderSet HTTP/1.1[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Accept: application/json[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"x-csrf-token: 38IQnzDSn6aZeqmFczbqQA==[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Content-Type: application/json[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Proxy-Authorization: Bearer eyJh...." }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"SAP-Connectivity-Authentication: Bearer eyJh...." }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"X-Requested-With: X-Requested-With[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"sap-language: en[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Content-Length: 1223[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Host: dev-gateway-cd:443[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11.0.8)[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Cookie: MYSAPSSO2=AjQxMDMBABhBAEwAMgAyADIANwA2ACAAIAAgACAAIAACAAY1ADUAMAADABBEAEcAVwAgACAAIAAgACAABAAYMgAwADIAMAAxADEAMQA5ADAANwA1ADQABQAEAAAACAYAAlgACQACRQD%2fASswggEnBgkqhkiG9w0BBwKgggEYMIIBFAIBATELMAkGBSsOAwIaBQAwCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMYH0MIHxAgEBMEcwOjEVMBMGA1UEChMMU0FQIFNlY3VyaXR5MSEwHwYDVQQDExhTZWN1cmUgTG9naW4gVXNlciBTdWIgQ0ECCQQz%21dD%2f97ncUTAJBgUrDgMCGgUAoF0wGAYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQUxDxcNMjAxMTE5MDc1NDU3WjAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQU4PBXYuos4C1Bm%21YztJ4J8CdsGQ4wCQYHKoZIzjgEAwQuMCwCFCavVSRTFJsKNa3srFhnEbOByT8GAhRHSbed50wUDAOB4AYClz%2ftvf3pYg%3d%3d; SAP_SESSIONID_DGW_550=4BFhS5Wq30GRv2nbzjuNh4RHkVUqPBHrpSgCOIUjX_g%3d; sap-usercontext=sap-language=en&sap-client=550[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.11+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 >> \"{\"DesNum\":\"290272\",\"PeItemSet\":[{\"InternPeId\":3,\"Taaklijst\":\"4316\",\"DesGuid\":\"02656ec2-ef0e-1edb-87b8-8a32b6cf28c7\",\"LevelCounter\":1,\"DesNum\":\"290272\",\"Supcunr\":2,\"Parcunr\":2,\"PeId\":\"43004631\",\"ProductID\":\"114010\",\"PeLevel\":3,\"PeTxt\":\"Aansluiting E AC4a tm 3x160A\",\"PeType\":\"1\",\"Uitvoeringsfactor\":\"1\",\"Eenheid\":\"ST\",\"SoortWerk\":\"00\"},{\"InternPeId\":2,\"Taaklijst\":\"2766\",\"DesGuid\":\"02656ec2-ef0e-1edb-87b8-8a32b6cf28c7\",\"LevelCounter\":1,\"DesNum\":\"290272\",\"Supcunr\":1,\"Parcunr\":2,\"PeId\":\"43003082\",\"ProductID\":\"114010\",\"PeLevel\":2,\"PeTxt\":\"E MAKEN AC4A AANSLUITING\",\"PeType\":\"V\",\"Uitvoeringsfactor\":\"1\",\"OptOmp\":false,\"SoortWerk\":\"05\",\"SoortWerkOmschrijving\":\"Uitbreiding\"},{\"InternPeId\":4,\"Taaklijst\":\"6317\",\"DesGuid\":\"02656ec2-ef0e-1edb-87b8-8a32b6cf28c7\",\"LevelCounter\":2,\"DesNum\":\"290272\",\"Supcunr\":1,\"Parcunr\":4,\"PeId\":\"43006902\",\"PeLevel\":2,\"PeTxt\":\"E Combi SION Baas Flevo\",\"PeType\":\"1\",\"Uitvoeringsfactor\":\"0\",\"Eenheid\":\"ST\",\"OptOmp\":false},{\"InternPeId\":5,\"Taaklijst\":\"4977\",\"DesGuid\":\"02656ec2-ef0e-1edb-87b8-8a32b6cf28c7\",\"LevelCounter\":3,\"DesNum\":\"290272\",\"Supcunr\":1,\"Parcunr\":5,\"PeId\":\"43005291\",\"PeLevel\":2,\"PeTxt\":\"ALG. PE-UREN - R\\u0026N\",\"PeType\":\"1\",\"Uitvoeringsfactor\":\"0\",\"Eenheid\":\"ST\",\"OptOmp\":false}]}\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.65+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"HTTP/1.1 201 Created[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.65+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.65+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"content-length: 739[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.65+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"dataserviceversion: 2.0[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.65+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"sap-processing-info: microhub=,crp=,st=,MedCacheHub=SHM,codeployed=,softstate=[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.65+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"sap-perf-fesrec: 523322.000000[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.65+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"content-encoding: gzip[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.65+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"location: http://dev-gateway-cd:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV/HeaderSet('290272')[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.65+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-15 << \"[\\r][\\n]\"" }

=== HEAD before function call (FinalizeConcept) - Return 403 Forbidden response and no CSRF token -
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.69+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"HEAD http://dev-gateway-cd:443/opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV HTTP/1.1[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.69+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"x-csrf-token: Fetch[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.69+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"Proxy-Authorization: Bearer eyJh...." }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.69+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"SAP-Connectivity-Authentication: Bearer eyJh...." }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.69+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"X-Requested-With: X-Requested-With[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.69+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"sap-language: en[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.69+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"Host: dev-gateway-cd:443[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.69+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.69+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11.0.8)[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.69+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.69+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"content-length: 188[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"Access denied to resource /opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV on system dev-gateway-cd:443. In case this was a valid request, ensure to expose the resource correctly in your cloud connector.\"" }

=== POST call function (FinalizeConcept) - Still executes request without CSRF token -
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"POST http://dev-gateway-cd:443/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV/FinalizeConcept?contractPositie='00001'&contract='4600001985'&desNum='290272'&$format=json HTTP/1.1[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"x-csrf-token: [\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"Proxy-Authorization: Bearer eyJh...." }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"SAP-Connectivity-Authentication: Bearer eyJh...." }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"X-Requested-With: X-Requested-With[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"sap-language: en[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"Host: dev-gateway-cd:443[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11.0.8)[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:54:57.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 >> \"[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"content-length: 856[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"dataserviceversion: 2.0[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"cache-control: no-cache, no-store[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"pragma: no-cache[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"sap-processing-info: microhub=,crp=,st=,MedCacheHub=SHM,codeployed=,softstate=[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"sap-perf-fesrec: 15758403.000000[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"set-cookie: sap-usercontext=sap-language=en&sap-client=550; path=/[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"set-cookie: MYSAPSSO2=AjQxMDMBABhBAEwAMgAyADIANwA2ACAAIAAgACAAIAACAAY1ADUAMAADABBEAEcAVwAgACAAIAAgACAABAAYMgAwADIAMAAxADEAMQA5ADAANwA1ADQABQAEAAAACAYAAlgACQACRQD%2fASswggEnBgkqhkiG9w0BBwKgggEYMIIBFAIBATELMAkGBSsOAwIaBQAwCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMYH0MIHxAgEBMEcwOjEVMBMGA1UEChMMU0FQIFNlY3VyaXR5MSEwHwYDVQQDExhTZWN1cmUgTG9naW4gVXNlciBTdWIgQ0ECCQQz%21dD%2f97ncUTAJBgUrDgMCGgUAoF0wGAYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQUxDxcNMjAxMTE5MDc1NDU3WjAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQU4PBXYuos4C1Bm%21YztJ4J8CdsGQ4wCQYHKoZIzjgEAwQuMCwCFAqryT5UyRSqtelnADn%214ExvPaHGAhQFUmkaZVG1UL%21iM4Wz3sb%21triClQ%3d%3d; path=/; domain=dev-gateway-cd; HttpOnly[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"set-cookie: SAP_SESSIONID_DGW_550=ufIRFLfZoVbkIXV-6RengoRHkVwqPBHrpSgCOIUjX_g%3d; path=/; HttpOnly[\\r][\\n]\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"[\\r][\\n]\"" }
=== We do seem to receive a response   
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"{\"d\":{\"__metadata\":{\"id\":\"https://vhanddgwci.hec.alliander.local:44300/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV/HeaderSet('290272')\",\"uri\":\"https://vhanddgwci.hec.alliander.local:44300/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV/HeaderSet('290272')\",\"type\":\"ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV.Header\"},\"Contract\":\"4600001985\",\"DesGuid\":\"02656ec2-ef0e-1edb-87b8-8a32b6cf28c7\",\"PsReference\":\"\",\"ContractPositie\":\"00001\",\"DesNum\":\"290272\",\"DesType\":\"D\",\"Ktext\":\"PMD - 20201103 Artemisweg 55 Lelystad\",\"OhOrganisatie\":\"2300\",\"OhPlanningsgroep\":\"MCR\",\"Werkplek\":\"IPRH\",\"OhPrestatie\":\"R&N\",\"BasisStart\":\"\\/Date(1596153600000)\\/\",\"BasisEinde\":\"\\/Date(1597363200000)\\/\",\"PeOrder\":\"4108510\",\"Bouwmaatregel\":\"223942\",\"Wbs\":\"IPR-21007813-0001\",\"PeItemSet\":{\"__deferred\":{\"uri\":\"https://vhanddgwci.hec.alliander.local:44300/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV/HeaderSet('290272')/PeItemSet\"}}}}\"" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: Access denied to resource /opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV on system dev-gateway-cd:443. In case this was a valid request, ensure to expose the resource correctly in your cloud connector.HTTP/1.1 200 OK" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: content-length: 856" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: dataserviceversion: 2.0" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: cache-control: no-cache, no-store" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: pragma: no-cache" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: sap-processing-info: microhub=,crp=,st=,MedCacheHub=SHM,codeployed=,softstate=" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: sap-perf-fesrec: 15758403.000000" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: set-cookie: sap-usercontext=sap-language=en&sap-client=550; path=/" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: set-cookie: MYSAPSSO2=AjQxMDMBABhBAEwAMgAyADIANwA2ACAAIAAgACAAIAACAAY1ADUAMAADABBEAEcAVwAgACAAIAAgACAABAAYMgAwADIAMAAxADEAMQA5ADAANwA1ADQABQAEAAAACAYAAlgACQACRQD%2fASswggEnBgkqhkiG9w0BBwKgggEYMIIBFAIBATELMAkGBSsOAwIaBQAwCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMYH0MIHxAgEBMEcwOjEVMBMGA1UEChMMU0FQIFNlY3VyaXR5MSEwHwYDVQQDExhTZWN1cmUgTG9naW4gVXNlciBTdWIgQ0ECCQQz%21dD%2f97ncUTAJBgUrDgMCGgUAoF0wGAYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQUxDxcNMjAxMTE5MDc1NDU3WjAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQU4PBXYuos4C1Bm%21YztJ4J8CdsGQ4wCQYHKoZIzjgEAwQuMCwCFAqryT5UyRSqtelnADn%214ExvPaHGAhQFUmkaZVG1UL%21iM4Wz3sb%21triClQ%3d%3d; path=/; domain=dev-gateway-cd; HttpOnly" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: set-cookie: SAP_SESSIONID_DGW_550=ufIRFLfZoVbkIXV-6RengoRHkVwqPBHrpSgCOIUjX_g%3d; path=/; HttpOnly" }
   2020-11-19T08:55:13.56+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser","level":"DEBUG","msg":"Garbage in response: " }

=== Finally a "Read timeout"
   2020-11-19T08:57:13.66+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT { "logger":"o.a.h.wire","level":"DEBUG","msg":"http-outgoing-16 << \"[read] I/O error: Read timed out\"" }
```

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a shortcoming in the SDK. In previous versions all create/update/delete/function requests would fail if CSRF token retrieval failed. This was improved for most of the code. But as of today (SDK version `3.33.0`) functions still have this behaviour.

---

If you really need a workaround today the following should work for queries that use `POST`:

```java
String servicePath = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV";
String functionCall = "CreateEntity?EntityKey='key'";

ODataRequestAction action = new ODataRequestAction(servicePath, functionCall, "", ODataProtocol.V2);

ODataRequestResultGeneric result = action.execute(HttpClientAccessor.getHttpClient(destination));

// in case there is a return value expected:
ResultFoo foo = result.as(ResultFoo.class);
```

This is not pretty since you have to hard-code most of the values. And it will also try to fetch a CSRF token. But crucially it will execute the request also with the token. You can prevent the SDK from fetching a CSRF token by setting a dummy value into the header: `action.addHeader(DefaultCsrfTokenRetriever.X_CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, "dummy")`

Comment: Yes, we really need a workaround. Will try to implement the example. Any timeline on when this will be fixed in the SDK?

Comment: Will this still result in a `403 Forbidden` if we try to get the CSRF token? So do we really need to add the dummy value?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give you a timeline as of today, but I'll be sure to update this answer if this is implemented.
No you don't have to add the dummy value. This is only helpful to improve performance because no request for CSRF tokens will be made at all.

Comment: Hi Danny, this is in our backlog to be fixed. Do you need it for a productive use? What's the urgency on your side?

Comment: Hi, the workaround solved our issue and is being used in production. Of course it would nice if we can stick to the higher abstactions provided by the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticing that the HEAD request for the function import call goes against a relative path which is unexpected: `http://host:port/opu/odata/sap/ZCU_PE_CONCEPT_SRV`
Normally OData APIs reside under the relative path `/sap/opu/odata/sap/here-comes-the-api`. You seem to miss the initial part `sap` in your relative path.

Can it be that you mistyped the path in your destination configuration?

Answer (score 0):

We finally ended up implementing the workaround by creating the following method, based on the example workaround:

```java
    private Header callFinalizeFunction(final ExternalId peConceptId, final ExternalId contractId, final String contractPosition, HttpDestination destination) {
        final String servicePath = ZCUPECONCEPTSRVService.DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH;
        Map<String, String> params = Map.of(
                "desNum", peConceptId.getValue(),
                "contract", contractId.getValue(),
                "contractPositie", contractPosition);
        String actionCall = "FinalizeConcept";
        ODataRequestAction action = new ODataRequestAction(servicePath, actionCall, "", ODataProtocol.V2);
        params.forEach((k,v) -> action.addQueryParameter(k, String.format("'%s'", v)));
        return action
                .execute(HttpClientAccessor.getHttpClient(destination))
                .as(Header.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SAP Cloud SDK 3.34.1 available since yesterday ships an improved function import call invocation so that a failing CSRF token retrieval **no longer breaks the function import** call, but continues issuing the request and thereafter processing the function import result.

This is mainly useful in case the server does not support or requires CSRF tokens for any reason.